# Prove/Disprove $ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (i!)^2 \not\equiv 0 (\text{mod } p)$.

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, modules

> Prove/Disprove  $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (i!)^2 \not\equiv 0 (\text{mod } p)$.

While I was trying [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4711971/979028), I had to show that $\displaystyle p \not\Bigg|\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (i!)^2$. So I tried to solve this but failed.
Here's my attempt.

\begin{align}
& \text{Approach 1. What's }[i!(p-1-i)!]^2 \text{ mod } p?\\
\ \\
& \text{Note. } {p-1 \choose i}^2 \equiv 1 (\text{mod } p). \\
\Rightarrow \; & \left[ \frac {(p-1)!} {i!(p-1-i)!} \right]^2 \equiv 1 (\text{mod }p). \\
& \text{By Wilson's theorem, } (p-1)! \equiv -1 (\text{mod } p). \\
\therefore \; & \left[i!(p-1-i)!\right]^2 \equiv 1 (\text{mod } p). \\
\ \\
& \text{Approach 2. How can } 2\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (i!)^2 \text{ change its form?} \\ 
&2\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} (i!)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \left\{(i!)^2+[(p-i)!]^2\right\}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \left\{ [i!+(p-i)!]^2 -2\cdot i!(p-i)!\right\}
\end{align}

Uh... Any tips?

Comment: Remember that when you want to write something like $\sum_{i=1}^n a+\sum_{i=1}^n b$, you have to write $\sum_{i=1}^n (a+b)$. Without the parenthesis, it becomes very hard to understand. I have already suggested an edit for you.

Comment: @IraeVid Ohh, I've missed that. I'll edit it...(I already voted for 'reject' in the suggested edits review... sorry for that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the statement is wrong. According to an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713516/question-about-the-divisibility-of-a-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1) the smallest counterexample is $p=1248829$

Comment: Oh, I see. It was my mistake that I didn't look for the other posts.