# Is there a prime number $p$ dividing $1+2!^2+3!^2+\cdots (p-1)!^2$?

Tags: summation, prime-numbers, divisibility, factorial

Is there a prime number $p$ with $p \mid \sum_{j=1}^{p-1} j!^2$?

I checked the primes upto $600\ 000$ without finding a solution.

Heuristic : If we can assume that the probability that $p$ is a solution is $\frac{1}{p}$ , then there should be infinite many solutions and therefore the desired prime should exist. But I guess this is not the case and maybe the special expression can easily be determined to be or not to be divisible by $p$.

Motivation : Such a prime number would prove that $1+2!^2+3!^2+\cdots n!^2$ can be prime only for finite many positive integers $n$ and also give an upper bound for the possible $n$. If the answer to the question is no , there is a chance that there are infinite many such primes.

Comment: Thank you for the downvoters since this is another proof that questions of this kind always will receive downvotes , even if not the slightest reason exists. I am pretty sure that we won't hear why this was downvoted (twice!) , but I do not care. Probably from people upvoting purely PSQ-questions , but considering such questions as "too arbitary".

Comment: This is a duplicate of your [own previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713516/question-about-the-divisibility-of-a-sum?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Your question is OK, as well as being distinct from your previous related question. We just have to get used to undeserved downvotes, which will always occur on this site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes. By running a script which computes this sum mod $p$ through the first $100\,000$ primes, I found one solution: $p = 1\,248\,829$ ($96\,379$th prime).

UPDATE. This is also the only solution for the first $1\,000\,000$ primes.

UPDATE 2. If the probability that $p$ is the solution is indeed $1/p$, it follows from the [Mertens' third theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems#Third_theorem), that the probability to find the solution between $10^{m-1}$th prime and $10^m$th prime is asymptotically $1/m$. This could explain our serendipitous finding, but also discourages to look any further.

Comment: Confirmed.  The $96\,379^{\text{th}}$ prime is $1\,248\,829$ and $\sum_{j=1}^{1\,248\,828}(j!)^2 \cong 0 \pmod{1\,248\,829}$.

Comment: Wow , I expected a much larger smallest solution (+1 and accept). Which tool did you use (PARI/GP takes already very long for $6\cdot 10^5$).

Comment: @Peter It takes about 15 minutes to run in C++ (not parallelized). The only optimization which I've used is that we don't need to compute each factorial from the start, reusing the result for the previous term, which makes the computation $O(p)$ per prime.

Answer (score 1):

Let's implement $S$ in Python to make large searches possible (for whoever is interested).

Let $S(m) = \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} (j!)^2$.  We want to focus our study on prime $m$, but let's have $S$ available for any positive integer $m \geq 2$.

(There is an extensive comment in the Markdown here.  It details an attempt to move directly from $S(m-1) = q_{m-1}(m-1) + r_{m-1}$ to $S(m) = q_m m + r_m$.  The result was no faster, so it is not presented.  Feel free to edit and read if you are somehow interested.)

The function `sPlain()` is a direct translation of the definition of $S$.  The function `sReuse` is an attempt to implement [Efim Mazhnik's description](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/574392/efim-mazhnik) of his code.  `Sconsecutive()` evaluates $S(m) \pmod{m}$ for $m =2, 3, 4, \dots$.  `SconsecutivePrimes()` evaluates $S(p) \pmod{p}$ for prime integers, $p = 2, 3, 5, \dots$.

(I find that `SconsecutivePrimes()` runs faster as (equivalent) Mathematica code.  Most likely, Mathematica tries harder to cache sieving partial results between `NextPrime[]` calls than does sympy for `nextprime()`, but I haven't really looked into it.)

`Sconsecutive()` has been run up to 3.1 million finding only $m \mid S(m)$ for $m = 1\,248\,829$.  `SconsecutivePrimes()` has been run up to 10 million and found no new successes.

```
from math import factorial

def Splain(m):
    retVal = 0
    for j in range(1, m):    # iterates over [1,m).
        retVal += factorial(j)**2
    return retVal

def Sreuse(m):
    retVal = 0
    jFactorialSquared = 1
    for j in range(1, m):
        jFactorialSquared *= j**2
        retVal += jFactorialSquared
    return retVal

def Sconsecutive():
    # Has been run to m = 3.1 million (and a little further); only found 1248829|S(1248829).
    m = 2  #  least m for which S(m) is not empty
    j = 1  #  new index in S(2) compared to S(1)
    jFactorialSquared = factorial(j)**2
    s = jFactorialSquared  #  S(m) = S(2) = 1!^2 = 1
    print("Runs forever.  Press <ctrl>-c (or whatever interrupts execution in your environment) to stop.")
    while True:
        if s % m == 0:
            print(" m | S(m) for m = ",  m)
        m+=1
        j += 1
        jFactorialSquared *= j**2
        s += jFactorialSquared
        if m % 100000 == 0:  #  Depending on your hardware, you might like feedback more frequently that every hundred thousand.
            print("About to test m = ",  m)

from sympy import nextprime
def SconsecutivePrimes():
    # Has been run to p = 10 million (and a little further); only found 1248829|S(1248829).
    p = 2  #  S(2) is first nonempty sum
    s = 1
    jTerm = 1    # = factorial(1)**2
    count = 1
    print("Runs forever.  Press <ctrl>-c (or whatever interrupts execution in your environment) to stop.")
    while True:
        if s % p == 0:
            print(" p | S(p) for p = ",  p)
        pNext = nextprime(p)
        # Note: sympy's nextprime() promises to deliver primes for p less 
        # than about 2^32.  For larger p, nextprime() seems to produce strong 
        # pseudoprimes to several bases.  It's fine that we use such ps, 
        # but we should rigorously check for primeness before reporting 
        # divisibility.  It's left as an exercise for the reader to use, 
        # for example, 
        #     https://github.com/wacchoz/APR_CL/blob/master/APR_CL.py
        # to modify the "if s % p == 0:" block above to check rigorously 
        # for primality before reporting a "success".
        s += sum ([ jTerm := jTerm * (j**2) for j in range(p,  pNext) ])
        p = pNext
        count +=1
    
        if count % 10000 == 0:
            print("# About to test p = ", p)

from decimal import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("The Splain() call may take longer than you expect.  The Sreuse() call will return much faster.")
    print("Splain(10,000) = ",  Splain(10_000))
    print("Sreuse(10,000) = ",  Sreuse(10_000))
    SconsecutivePrimes()
```